# Parse error using Java8 LocalDateTime Iso date format

Tags: java, java-8, date-formatting

I use Java 8 New Date variable "LocalDateTime" to convert string in a method:

```
    @Override
    public Object getAsDate(String value) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;

        return LocalDateTime.parse(value);
    }
```

When I call this method with my value, I get a "could not be parsed" error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-10-20 18-20-03' could not be parsed at index 10
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:477)
```

I don't know if I missed something.

Comment: Hi, yes you missed creating a [mcve], Too much to read/filter now. And try creating a unittest for the string in the error, the error is valid/logical, it is not an iso date. Totally not jsf or jpa related.

Comment: I edited your Q to contain only that code tgat could be in a unit test.

Comment: @Kukeltje I didn't know that my issue is not related to JSF or JPA, I wanted to give maximum information so others can understand my code and give help. I don't think that deserves (-2).

Comment: Asking questions is not about providing maximum information, it is about providing relevant and on topic information. It might even be that providing lots of irrelevant info scares people of (providing 'wrong' tags is one of them). That is what root cause analysis is with help of creating a [mcve]. Did you btw notice both your patterns for converting look different? Creating an simple unittest would have been not too difficult, as would have been posting the error in google, so the downvote most likely is because of that, no mcve, to much info, no research See e.g. http://idownvotedbecau.se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@Override
public Object getAsDate(String value) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");

    return formatter.parse(value);
}
```